# What is context in Jinja2?

Tags: python, templates, django-templates, jinja2

jinja_code.py

```
import jinja2
env=jinja2.Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./"))
template=env.get_template('file.j2')
render_template=template.render(test1="TEST1",test2="TEST2")
print(render_template)
```

file.j2

```
{{ context.test1 }}
```

I'm learning Jinja2 and I understood that context are the variables that are passed to Template but when I execute the above code, i get the below error

```
jinja2.exceptions.undefinederror: 'context' is not defined
```

I've read the docs and I couldn't understand it completely. Can you please explain what is context and how it is used to access the variables?

Comment: try `{{test1}}` without context

Comment: Yes I know that works. But I've seen a code where the user simply wrote {% set name = context.FirstName %}. So I'm confused where does that context gets loaded from?

Answer (score 2):

Context contains the dynamic content that you want to inject in your template when it is being rendered.

In your example, the file **file.j2** must have the following content:

```
{{ test1 }}
```

As context is not a variable but the collection of all variables you pass to the template. **test1** and **test2** are part of the context.

Comment: But I've seen a code where the user simply wrote {% set name = context.FirstName %}. So can you please explain how will it be handled?

Comment: If you need to use  {{ context.test1 }}, you need to pass it to your template as a dict in the following way: 
render_template=template.render(context={"test1":"TEST1","test2":"TEST2"})

Answer (score 1):

The following is the signature of render_template:

```
def render_template(
    template_name_or_list: t.Union[str, Template, t.List[t.Union[str, Template]]],
    **context: t.Any
) -> str
```

`context` parameter is preceeded by two asterisks indicating that an arbitrary number of named parameters can be passed. Accordingly, the statement `template.render(test1="TEST1",test2="TEST2")` will result in having a dictionary passed through the `context` parameter as such: `{'test1': 'TEST1', 'test2': 'TEST2'}`.

Jinja will unpack `context` automatically behind the scenes as follows and accordingly, you do not have to do that since it's already done for you:

```
test1 = context['test1']
test2 = context['test2']
```

You can then use `test1` directly:

```
{{ test1 }}
```